# JavaFX Accordion set next expanded Pane

Tags: java, javafx, accordion

In Accordion it is possible to set the selected Pane with `accordion.setExpandedPane`, and it is also possible to get all the children with `accordion.getPanes()`.

However I'm struggling to find how to implement "select next Pane" functionality without explicitly extending the TitledPane class for the Panes, and maintaining an index manually via `accordion.expandedPaneProperty()` and some custom implementation.

A Proposed solution would be to add a listened to `expandedPaneProperty()`:

```
    accordion.expandedPaneProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if(null != newValue){
            idx = 0;
            for(TitledPane whytho: this.getPanes()){
                if(!whytho.equals(newValue))idx++;
                else break;
            }
            selectedIndex = idx;
        }
    });
```

Is there an easier way for this?

Comment: Why not query the index of the expanded pane ([`List#indexOf(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object))) and then expand the pane at `index ± 1` (wrapping around if needed/wanted).

Comment: I think that's what I was looking for! Thanks! Would you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query the index of the currently expanded pane using [`List#indexOf(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)). Then you just need to set the expanded pane to the pane at `index ± 1`.

```
private void expandPrevious(Accordion acc) {
    int index = acc.getPanes().indexOf(acc.getExpandedPane());
    int newIndex = Math.max(index - 1, 0);
    acc.setExpandedPane(acc.getPanes().get(newIndex));
}

private void expandNext(Accordion acc) {
    int index = acc.getPanes().indexOf(acc.getExpandedPane());
    int newIndex = Math.min(index + 1, acc.getPanes().size() - 1);
    acc.setExpandedPane(acc.getPanes().get(newIndex));
}
```

The above doesn't perform any wrap around logic; in other words, calling `expandNext` while the last pane is expanded won't expand the first pane—rather nothing will change. It also doesn't handle the case where `getExpandedPane()` returns `null`.